# Picasso. Image loaded on the 2 attempt

Tags: java, android

With Picasso library I load Bitmap by url.
Here my code:

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private String imageUrl = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532793647389-1d8cf566cae6?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e2bd210796f1313a943261973b470ae8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        Log.d("MyLog", "BitmapLoaded");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

But this code doesn't work on my real devise. "onBitmapLoaded" doesn't called.

But when I run this app on my emulator it works on the second attempt.

I don't unedrstand why it's happen?

Comment: seems ok, have you tried loading image through Glide?

Comment: @Amir De, No. But, is Picasso bad library?

Comment: no it isn't .. i was just saying you can try glide as well. that's what i use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because; `Picasso` keeps `Target` as a `weak reference`. Can you please try to define your `Target` as a global variable in your class and reload image again?

```
    private final Target myTarget = new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        Log.d("MyLog", "BitmapLoaded");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable)   {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                    }
            }
```

And load like below:

```
Picasso.get()
       .load(imageUrl)
       .into(myTarget);
```

This way your `Target` object has a strong reference and will not be collected immediately by the `GC`.

Comment: you think this error is because of weak reference in Picasso? because `into()` may get a `View` it may use weak reference to prevent resource leak. and if we do not hold a reference to `myTarget` it may get garbage collected

Comment: @savepopulation, it seems it works! It's really strange - when 'target' is global variable it works on my phone and emulator, but when 'target' is  local variable - it works only on emulator. The reason is different garbage collectors?

Comment: do you use same android version in emulator?

Comment: @savepopulation, no, 5.1 and 8.1

Comment: your questions answer is yes. also it can be changed according to device's resources.